# I'm looking for a search pagination code. My code give properly result but not working in pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, search, pagination

I've set a search result, and I have 6 result on home page (correct), but if I have 7 or more result result not showing pagination. Here is my code:

```
function search_results(){
// Search list will show from here
if( isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['services']) ){
    // search code
    $city = isset($_REQUEST['city']) ? $_REQUEST['city'] : '';


    $service_name = isset($_REQUEST['services']) ? $_REQUEST['services'] : '';

    // service_name

    $num_rec_per_page  = 6;

    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Comment: what it returns?

Comment: Some code seems to be missing. Where is your query?

Comment: Maybe you are having issues in setting up a proper query. And I dont know if you directly call the DB in WP or use an ORM. But reading this might help: https://www.guru99.com/limit.html